# WiFi stops working in Ubuntu 22.04 when dual booting with Windows 11

Tags: networking, drivers, dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 alongside Windows 11 on my HP Pavillion laptop, but when I boot into Ubuntu (from both turned off PC and from Windows), the WiFI is connected normally, I can search in browser or ping via cmd, but it then, usually after about 10 seconds after boot, suddenly crashes, showing the "Activation of network failed", and I can no longer see any networks in the "Select Network" window. As the connection is up for a little while after booting up, I suppose the issue is with the drivers, but I was not able to figure out what exactly the issue might be.

Based on the related issues I found, I already tried disabling the "fast boot" and both sleep and hibernate in Windows, which did not do anything. Update & upgrade also did not work, and there are also no Additional Drivers in Software & Updates. I tried to remove the driver with `modprobe -r rtw89_8852be` and then reinsert it with `modprobe rtw89_8852be`, but the reinsert only resulted in `modprobe: FATAL: Module rtw89_8852be not found in directory /lib/modules/6.2.0-37-generic`. I tried to install the drivers manually following [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2484689) guide, but the reinsert ended up on the same error.

Result of  `lspci -v`:

```
    DeviceName: Realtek Wireless LAN + BT
    !!! Unknown header type 7f
    Kernel driver in use: rtw89_8852be
    Kernel modules: rtw_8852be
```

I tried to find something about the header type warning, but I did not find anything that could help me, so I went to ask directly on the forum since I am not really good with OS stuff. Thanks in advance for any tips.

**Edit - added output of `/var/log/syslog` at the moment of disconnection**

```
Dec  6 11:14:59 martin-HP kernel: [  269.084149] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:14:59 martin-HP kernel: [  269.084184] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: write rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:14:59 martin-HP kernel: [  269.089356] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: FW does not process h2c registers
Dec  6 11:14:59 martin-HP kernel: [  269.089366] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: HW scan failed with status: -110
Dec  6 11:14:59 martin-HP wpa_supplicant[630]: message repeated 2 times: [ wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-110 retry=1]
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP NetworkManager[592]: <warn>  [1701857700.6922] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP NetworkManager[592]: <info>  [1701857700.6922] device (wlo1): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP wpa_supplicant[630]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP NetworkManager[592]: <info>  [1701857700.6928] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP NetworkManager[592]: <warn>  [1701857700.6934] device (wlo1): Activation: failed for connection 'hellothere'
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP NetworkManager[592]: <info>  [1701857700.6938] device (wlo1): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.108574] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: Update probe request failed
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.217546] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: FW does not process h2c registers
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.217798] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.217843] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.217883] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: write rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.217920] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: write rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.217958] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.217997] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.218036] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.218076] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.218115] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.218154] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.218193] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.218233] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.218272] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.218311] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.218350] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.218390] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.218429] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.218468] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.218508] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.218547] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.218584] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.218621] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.218658] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.218695] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.218735] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.218772] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.218809] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.218846] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.218883] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.218921] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.218957] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.218995] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.219030] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: write rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.219065] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: write rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.219101] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: write rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.219136] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.219171] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.219206] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: write rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.219241] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: write rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.219276] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: write rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.219311] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.219350] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: write rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.219385] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: write rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.219425] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: write rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.219459] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: write rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.219495] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.219530] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.219574] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: write rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.219611] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: write rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.219646] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: write rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.219682] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.219717] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: write rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.219752] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: write rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.219788] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: write rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.219823] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: write rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.219858] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.219893] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: write rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.225471] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: FW does not process h2c registers
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP kernel: [  270.225481] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: HW scan failed with status: -110
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP wpa_supplicant[630]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-110
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP NetworkManager[592]: <info>  [1701857700.9218] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
Dec  6 11:15:00 martin-HP NetworkManager[592]: <info>  [1701857700.9219] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> inactive
Dec  6 11:15:01 martin-HP NetworkManager[592]: <info>  [1701857701.2018] policy: auto-activating connection 'hellothere' (35ea8db6-9248-4409-847d-44587468f5e9)
Dec  6 11:15:01 martin-HP NetworkManager[592]: <info>  [1701857701.2030] device (wlo1): Activation: starting connection 'hellothere' (35ea8db6-9248-4409-847d-44587468f5e9)
Dec  6 11:15:01 martin-HP NetworkManager[592]: <info>  [1701857701.2032] device (wlo1): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec  6 11:15:01 martin-HP NetworkManager[592]: <info>  [1701857701.2038] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Dec  6 11:15:01 martin-HP NetworkManager[592]: <info>  [1701857701.2041] device (wlo1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec  6 11:15:01 martin-HP NetworkManager[592]: <info>  [1701857701.2046] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) access point 'hellothere' has security, but secrets are required.
Dec  6 11:15:01 martin-HP NetworkManager[592]: <info>  [1701857701.2047] device (wlo1): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec  6 11:15:01 martin-HP NetworkManager[592]: <info>  [1701857701.2060] device (wlo1): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec  6 11:15:01 martin-HP NetworkManager[592]: <info>  [1701857701.2062] device (wlo1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec  6 11:15:01 martin-HP NetworkManager[592]: <info>  [1701857701.2065] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) connection 'hellothere' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Dec  6 11:15:01 martin-HP NetworkManager[592]: <info>  [1701857701.2066] Config: added 'ssid' value 'hellothere'
Dec  6 11:15:01 martin-HP NetworkManager[592]: <info>  [1701857701.2066] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Dec  6 11:15:01 martin-HP NetworkManager[592]: <info>  [1701857701.2067] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Dec  6 11:15:01 martin-HP NetworkManager[592]: <info>  [1701857701.2067] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
Dec  6 11:15:01 martin-HP NetworkManager[592]: <info>  [1701857701.2067] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Dec  6 11:15:01 martin-HP NetworkManager[592]: <info>  [1701857701.2068] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Dec  6 11:15:01 martin-HP kernel: [  270.632535] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: Update probe request failed
Dec  6 11:15:01 martin-HP kernel: [  270.742402] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: FW does not process h2c registers
Dec  6 11:15:01 martin-HP kernel: [  270.742648] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
Dec  6 11:15:01 martin-HP kernel: [  270.742693] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: read rf busy swsi
```

Comment: What does `/var/log/syslog` show, especially at the time of the disconnect?

Comment: @ckhan I added the output of `syslog` as edit to the original question so it could fit

Comment: Googling these error  messages took me to: https://askubuntu.com/questions/630306/wlan-problem-wlan0-wireless-association-took-too-long-failing-activation. Consider the suggestions in there?